# How can I nest onMouseOver and onClick events in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, onmouseover

Already searched a lot but still can't solve it. I know how to make it with jQuery, but don't want to for this one.

The gif shows what I want: to trigger `onMouseOver` event **only if** the mouse button is pressed.

[gif example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AYwp.gif)

**Code Sample** (inside the ES6 Class):

I used map through an array to render the grid, so every square will have the mouse event. I removed some unnecessary info to help.

```
someMethod() {
   ***toggle CSS***
}

render() {    
  return <div>
            {this.state.array.map((item, index) => (
               <div onMouseOver={() => {this.someMethod(item, index)}} className={item.key}></div>
            ))}
         </div>
}
```

I can use `oneMouseOver` or `onClick` event, but how to merge them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set global mousedown and mouseup events (`document.body.addEventListener('mousedown')`) in which you change a global variable, or modify something in the state. A `mouseButtonIsDepressed` property or something along those lines. `mousedown` sets it to true, `mouseup` false. then in your `onMouseOver`, check to see whether or not that property is true.

Comment: It worked! Addendum: I just added the global `mousedown` and `mouseup` events inside the `constructor()` changing a variable to true and false. Also had to add two events to the <div> since `onClick` alone was still needed to be implemented. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both and use one method for each event type

```
mouseOverHandler(item, index){
 if(this.state.wasClicked){
  // executes only if the event click was triggered 
 }
}
    <div 
        onMouseOver={() => {this.mouseOverHandler(item, index)}} 
        onClick={() => {this.clickHandler(item, index)}} 
        className={item.key}>
    </div>
```